# Simple Image Processing for Android

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap

I need a simple image processing library that i can do auto local thresholding on a bitmap on Android .

I searched over the net but i cannot find a simple library that can do that. Can someone suggest a library or a method for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library jhlabs have a lot of image filters that you can use.

It is easy to add as a library to your project and easy to use.

Take a look at https://code.google.com/p/android-jhlabs/ and see if some of the filters is the one that you want.

Comment: Thanks. Thats a great library and exactly what i need.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17445432/color-replacer-in-android/17445542#17445542):

[Aviary SDK](http://www.aviary.com/android)
 [-> And the code for it.](https://github.com/AviaryInc/Mobile-Feather-SDK-for-Android)

[Here](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/learning/tutorials/) you can find a nice tutorial for all kinds of image processing.

Here you can find some libraries :

- ImageJ, http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/
- Fiji, http://fiji.sc/wiki/index.php/Fiji
- IMMI, http://splab.cz/immi

And finally this project [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-image-filtering/).

Have a nice reading :-)